# How to write the equivalent of this Java encryption function in the Node JS

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, typescript, rsa

This is the function used to encrypt in java

```
 public static String encryptionFunction(String fieldValue, String pemFileLocation) {
    try {

        // Read key from file
        String strKeyPEM = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pemFileLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            strKeyPEM += line + "\n";
        }
        br.close();
        String publicKeyPEM = strKeyPEM;
        System.out.println(publicKeyPEM);
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "");
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replaceAll("\\s", "");;
        byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPEM);
        // byte[] encoded = Base64.decode(publicKeyPEM);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = (PublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(fieldValue.getBytes());
        if (cipherData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int len = cipherData.length;
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if ((cipherData[i] & 0xFF) < 16) {
                str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(cipherData[i] & 0xFF);
            } else {
                str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(cipherData[i] & 0xFF);
            }
        }
        return str.trim();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("oops2");
        System.out.println(e);

    }
    return null;
}
```

I want the equivalent of this in javascript/Nodejs, i tried this:

```
import * as NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';

private encryptionFunction(fieldValue: string , pemkey: string) : string {
    const rsa  = new NodeRSA(pemkey);
    const encrypted= rsa.encrypt(fieldValue , 'hex')
    return encrypted

}
```

But the output size of both functions is the same, but apparently the encryption type is wrong.

Comment: Can you share what the error is?

Comment: I am sorry but your question is really confuse. First I though you wanted the java script code equivalent to the first function but in the second function you're trying a java code to encrypt using a `node-rsa` encryptation. So you want the java script code or the same encryptation result of another java script function not showed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node-RSA applies OAEP ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa#options)) as padding by default, so the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding used in the Java code must be explicitly specified. This has to be added after key import and before encryption:

```js
rsa.setOptions({ encryptionScheme: 'pkcs1' });
```

Alternatively, the padding can be specified directly during key import:

```js
const rsa  = new NodeRSA(pemkey, { encryptionScheme: 'pkcs1' });
```

With this change, both codes are functionally identical.

---

Regarding testing: Keep in  mind that RSA encryption is not deterministic, i.e. given the *same input* (key, plaintext), each encryption provides a *different ciphertext*. Therefore, the ciphertexts of both (functionally identical) codes will be different even if the input is identical. So this is not a bug, but the expected behavior.
How then can the equivalence of both codes be proved? E.g. by decrypting both ciphertexts with the *same* code/tool.